# How to override Floating Action Button in fragment?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have FAB in MainActivity. Activity itself contains a lot of fragments, I want to do specific action in mapsFragment with FAB. How can I override FAB for this fragment?

Comment: Just put FAB in your mapsFragment layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check in your Activity FAB onClick method if your Fragment is visible. Don't forget to add Tag when adding or replacing fragment.

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT_TAG");
if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
   // override fab click logic for fragment here

   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I just made activity fab invisible on attach, and created new locationFab for mapsFragment. On detach I am making fab visible again